# What is @ControllerAdvice annotation in spring-boot and why we use it and when?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm using custom framework in my work built on spring-boot framework , and i see this annotation `@ControllerAdvice` in spring-boot when i need it to create custom exception handler class but i don't know why i must use it ?

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ControllerAdvice.html, https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-controller-advice

Answer (score 21, accepted):

@**ControllerAdvice** is very useful to handle exceptions when you have multiple Spring REST API controllers doing a lot of different work.

That means when writing any application you encounter exceptions and to handle them at each method level is tedious and not optimal. So in order to overcome that,  spring has introduced the concept of `@ControllerAdvice` which will intercept all the controllers and look for the exceptions thrown.
This is at a global level means you only have one `@ControllerAdvice` for each application and it will intercept the exceptions thrown by the controllers in that particular application context.
[For more information](https://medium.com/@jovannypcg/understanding-springs-controlleradvice-cd96a364033f)

**Note**: It should be used only with spring MVC controllers.

Comment: are there other spring controllers ?

Comment: I mean to say @ControllerAdivce can only be used with controllers created with the Spring MVC framework and not with the controllers created with other frameworks like Jersey.